# Is it possible to convert a polynomial into a system of linear equations?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

We know about polynomials. A polynomial equation of $n^{th}$ degree would be:

$$a_1x^n + a_2x^{n-1} + a_3x^{n-3} + ... + a_n = 0$$

I have also been told that it's quite *difficult* to solve polynomial equations above degree 2.

But is it possible with some manipulation of the coefficients, to convert that polynomial, into a system of $n$ linear equations, such that solving the system would give me the all the roots of the polynomial equations?

Comment: The short answer is no.  General polynomial so of degree greater than $5$ cannot be solved in radicals.  However radicals are beyond the reach of linear algebra.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Why not?

Comment: Because polynomials are not linear for $n > 1$

Comment: @ManuelGuillen Polynomials arent linear, Im quite aware of that. I want to find roots of it, so I'm looking for transformation to $n$ linear equations instead.

Comment: You can't break down something such as $x^2 = 1$ into a system of linear equations, because if you tried, the coefficients would not be constant. If thats not enough proof, @MichaelBurr made the valid point that its been proven that it is impossible to derive a formula for the roots of a polynomial of order greater than or equal to 5.

Comment: @ManuelGuillen of order greater than *four*.

Comment: @Manuel, there's a difference between "cannot be solved in radicals" and "impossible to derive a formula" ; the first is correct, but [the second one isn't](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291909).

Comment: Pritt: you might want to see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84034).

Comment: If your question is if there exists a linear system with the roots as solutions, the answer is there exists infinitely many (possibly with complex coefficients).  However IMHO there is no way to get any of those linear systems without first solving the roots in the first place, or of equivalent complexity! So the approach isn't helpful.

Comment: @Macavity Thanks for your insight. But how can you **confidently** state that there's no way? Couldn't it be that a way hasn't been discovered yet?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal That's why I mentioned it's my opinion. Nothing stops future possibilities, but at this moment that's in the realm of conjecture.